# Google + plus sign in not working after android 6 release

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-signin

So, before android 6 marshmallow release, google + sign in worked perfectly. After release, Im having issues like permissions, onConnectionFailed, etc... Does anybody has a solution how to fix this? Im calling google sign in methods from fragment. Here is the code:

Fragment:

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("GoogleApiClient", "onConnected");
    mShouldResolve = false;
    new RetrieveTokenTask().execute(Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d("GoogleApiClient", "onConnectionSuspended   " + String.valueOf(i));
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d("GoogleApiClient", "onConnectionFailed");
    Log.d("GoogleApiCLient", connectionResult.toString());
    ViewUtils.hideProgressDialog();
    if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
                mIsResolving = true;
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e("LoginFragment", "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                mIsResolving = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i("RequestCode", String.valueOf(requestCode));
    Log.i("ResultCode", String.valueOf(resultCode));
    try {
        Log.i("Intent", data.getAction());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further.
        ViewUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.loading_dialog_str));
        if (resultCode != getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            mShouldResolve = false;
        }

        mIsResolving = false;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            new RetrieveTokenTask().execute(Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient));
        }

    } else {
        //facebook
        Log.d("Login", "FaceBook");
        mCallbackManagerFacebook.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static final String TAG = "RetrieveAccessToken";
    private static final int REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED = 55664;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        String scopes = "oauth2:profile";
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.d("Token", "Token Value: " + s);
        if (s == null) {
            ViewUtils.hideProgressDialog();
            ViewUtils.showToastMessage(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.login_error));
        } else {
            loginGoogleUser(s);
        }


        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

and activities on result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    LoginFragment loginFragment = (LoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyProfileFragment");
    if (loginFragment != null) {
        loginFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so, first of all, you need to change all of your dependencies of google play services to 8.1.0, also, build.gradle to the newest version, targeted sdk 23, comiled version 23, etc. So, basicaly, check your gradle. After that, you need to change your mGoogleApiClient to :

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

And finally, you need to include permissions you need for sdk>= 23. To do that, create

```
 private static String ACCOUNT_PERMISSIONS[] = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
};
```

Here is a good tutorial on how to get permissions for sdk >= 23:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions